# How to set function.events.sns.arn in a serverless.ts file?

Tags: serverless-framework

I am setting up a new Serverless TypeScript monorepo, using the `aws-nodejs-typescript` template. The template produces a `serverless.ts` file for configuration.

Adding an AWS SNS event listener for an existing SNS Topic is supported:

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sns/

However, there is no corresponding attribute in the type definitions for the sns event:

```
TS2322: Type ‘{ arn: string; }’ is not assignable to type ‘Sns’. Object literal may only specify known properties, and ‘arn’ does not exist in type ‘Sns’.

awsProvider.d.ts(487, 9): The expected type comes from property ‘sns’ which is declared here on type ‘Event’
```

How can I configure an event for an existing SNS Topic using `serverless.ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is .. type coercion! Had to downcast to unknown, then upcast to the Sns event type. Here's a minimal `serverless.ts` from my setup:

```
import type { Serverless, ApiGateway, Sns } from 'serverless/aws';

const serverlessConfiguration: Serverless = {
  service: {
    name: 'foo',
  },
  frameworkVersion: '2',
  custom: {
    webpack: {
      webpackConfig: './webpack.config.js',
      packager: 'yarn',
      includeModules: true,
    },
  },
  package: {
    individually: true,
  },
  plugins: ['serverless-webpack', 'serverless-jest-plugin'],
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs12.x',
    region: 'us-west-2',
    stage: "${opt:stage, 'dev'}",
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
      shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    } as ApiGateway,
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
    },
  },
  functions: {
    bar: {
      handler: 'src/baz.handler',
      timeout: 900,
      reservedConcurrency: 1,
      events: [
        {
          sns: ({
            arn:
              '${cf:another-stack.TopicArn}',
          } as unknown) as Sns,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

Comment: can you provide more details what is `'${cf:another-stack.TopicArn}',`?

Comment: Yes @bensiu, `'${cf:another-stack.TopicArn}'` is one of these, referencing a topic defined in another CloudFormation (cf) stack: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-cloudformation-outputs